# How to correct this my derivative sign is appears on top line can anyone help me

Tags: cases

```
\begin{equation}\tag{A}
\left
  .\begin{array}{ll}
    \xi{} = -x, & y(x) = y(-\xi{}) = y_{0}(\xi) \\
    y^{'}(x) = -y^{'}_{0}(\xi{}), & y^{''}(x) = -y^{''}_{0}(\xi{})
  \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
```

Comment: you should give a complete MWE post. use "CTRL K" button to place your code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Remove `\left.` and `\right.` which do nothing, and type `y'` instead of `y^{'}`; `y''` instead of `y^{''}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for :

```
\begin{equation}\tag{A}
\left
  .\begin{array}{ll}
    \xi{} = -x, & y(x) = y(-\xi{}) = y_{0}(\xi) \\
    y'(x) = -y'_{0}(\xi{}), & y''(x) = -y''_{0}(\xi{})
  \end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've seen several times the wrong input

```
y^{'}   y^{''}
```

which should be

```
y'  y''
```

The apostrophe is translated internally into `^{\prime}`, when single, into `^{\prime\prime}` when doubled.

Your code also has useless `\left.` and `\right.` commands.

I suggest using `aligned` for that display. Depending on your preferences you can align the two blocks at the `=` or at the left.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\tag{A}
\begin{aligned}
  \xi   &= -x,           & y(x)   &= y(-\xi) = y_{0}(\xi) \\
  y'(x) &= -y'_{0}(\xi), & y''(x) &= -y''_{0}(\xi)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\tag{B}
\begin{aligned}
  & \xi = -x,             && y(x) = y(-\xi) = y_{0}(\xi) \\
  & y'(x) = -y'_{0}(\xi), && y''(x) = -y''_{0}(\xi)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]